# issue in client side when calling method from service, IIS7

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7

I have issue "The caller was not authenticated by the service." when calling service method from IIS7 in client side. The client and service are in different machines. But when I am giving credentials its work fine. So, is any way to call service method without credentials and without this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, the service sounds like it has been configured to demand credentials.  This service has been designed to not only require that you pass credentials but also to prevent you from circumventing the security measures.

The bottom line is that if the service requires credentials, you must provide them. Is there a specific reason that you cannot or will not provide credentials to the service?